# How can I query PayPal for a list of transactions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've been looking through the PayPal developer documentation, but things are a bit confusing. I've found the Express Checkout - NVP/SOAP documentation, but it is listed as deprecated. I don't want to implement something that will go away soon or is outdated.

What API call should I use to retrieve a list of transactions/payments from PayPal?

Comment: it depends on which integration that you are using. Each NVP/SOAP and REST does not share a same API for listing out a transaction done.

Answer (score 1):

***Use PayPal rest API Lists payments***: It will list all payments, that were created by the *create payment* call using PayPal *rest API* and that are in any state.

The list shows the all payments that are made to the merchant who makes the call.

```
Sample CURL Request:

curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
count=10&start_index=0&sort_by=update_time&sort_order=asc \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

For more info, check PayPal rest API [payment documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/)

Comment: Thank you! I can't find the documentation that outlines acceptable parameters for payments/ like... paymentcount. Any idea where I can find this?

Comment: Thank you!, go to URL [Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/) and try to find the "List Payments" using browser's find method. It will be second option.